# Please help with this probalility problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Vince buys a box of candy that consists of six chocolate pieces, four fruit pieces and two mint pieces.  He selects three pieces of candy at random without replacement.

> 1. Calculate the probability that the first piece selected will be fruit flavored and the other two will be mint.
> 2. Calculate the probability that all three pieces selected will be the same type of candy.

Comment: Do you have any preliminary thoughts? Perhaps, some rough sketch or some preliminary thoughts. If you could elaborate a little on your preliminary thoughts you will get better help.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are a total of $6+4+2=12$ candies and candies are **not replaced**, notice that:
$$\begin{align*}
P(\text{fruit} \to \text{mint} \to \text{mint}) &= P(\text{fruit})P(\text{mint | fruit})P(\text{mint | fruit,mint}) \\
&= \frac{4}{12}\cdot\frac{2}{11}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{11}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\\
&= \frac{1}{165}
\end{align*}$$

Can you see why the $12$ decreased to $11$ and then to $10$? Can you see why the $2$ decreased to $1$?

> **Side Note:** If **replacement was allowed**, then we would instead calculate:
>   $$\frac{4}{12}\cdot\frac{2}{12}\cdot\frac{2}{12}$$

See if you can do the second one.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For the first part, employ **negative binomial** distribution. For the second part, employ **hypergeometric** distribution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints for the first question**

1. In how many ways can Vince select 3 pieces of candy without replacement?
2. In how many ways can Vince select 3 pieces of candy such that 1 is fruit flavored and the other two mint?

Comment: Order matters in 2.